# Unable to purchase online rail tickets from Busan to Seoul

Tags: trains, tickets, online-resources, south-korea

I've planned a trip to Busan and Seoul in a few weeks with the hotels booked and everything with the exception of getting to Seoul from Busan. I am planning to take the KTX train on the Gyeongbu express line to view the country side of Korea to Seoul. The issue is that I have been trying to access the Korail site but unable to connect. I have already contacted their customer service for help but no reply. I will be leaving to Seoul after staying in Busan for 3 days.

If I am still unable to buy the tickets online, I plan to go to the train station in Busan once I land to see if train tickets are still available. Do train tickets of this travel sell out quick? Are there other sites that allow me to buy train tickets for this type of travel or is Korail the only site? I ideally want to take the train to Seoul, and my backup plan is to buy a last minute plane ticket.

Edit:  **Disclaimer** I am just a traveler looking for answers and not promoting Korail in any way.

Comment: In my experience the train stations in South Korea are well laid out, modern, fast, and efficient. I never booked a ticket in advance but just went to the station and bought one from the many many ticket machines. Just be sure to know which kind of train, platform number, and departure time. Note that I only ever travelled between Busan and Seoul on the slowest/cheapest kind of train available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trains are very frequent between Busan & Seoul, you should be able to get KTX tickets very easily at Busan station. (Better if it is not a Saturday or Sunday!)

Comment: To be more specific, there are 50-60 services per day between the cities, meaning several trains per hour.